# SMTP settings using Godaddy mail with Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, actionmailer

How should I set up my SMTP settings in my initializer file using Godaddy mail?

Comment: are you asking for the godaddy smtp settings? or how to set them in a rails app?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Shamelessly taken from the article here: http://pilotoutlook.wordpress.com/2008/10/13/setup-email-in-ruby-on-rails-using-godaddysmtp/

Open `ROOT/config/environment.rb` file
For sendmail, add following lines -

```
ActionMailer::Base.delivery_method = :sendmail
ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {
:domain  => ‘www.example.com’
}
```

For Godaddy, add following lines -

```
ActionMailer::Base.delivery_method = :smtp
ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {
:address => ‘smtpout.secureserver.net’,
:domain  => ‘www.example.com’,
:port      => 80,
:user_name => ‘johndoe@example.com’,
:password => ‘yourpassword’,
:authentication => :plain
}
```

Save and restart your webserver. You are all set.

Remember that you can only send 300 emails per day from Godaddy, so if you need to send more emails, you will have to use sendmail or some other solution.

**Note the port is NOT set to 25** - this is on purpose.  GoDaddy's email servers are configured to use several ports, just in case 25 is blocked.

Comment: Note-- it should be ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings

Comment: Excellent point -- looks like server_settings was deprecated and replaced with smtp_settings over 5 years ago.  My bad.

Answer (score 6):

```
# config/environments/production.rb
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
  :address => 'smtpout.secureserver.net',
  :domain  => 'www.example.com',
  :port      => 80,
  :user_name => 'johndoe@example.com',
  :password => 'yourpassword',
  :authentication => :plain
}
```